# Vagrant box and iptables

Tags: ssh, vagrant, iptables

I have a problem with local vagrant box and iptables. 
I'm using vagrant with `chef/centos-6.6` box. 
I'd like to configure the iptables so default policy would be DROP everything and enable only certain ports. 
Here is my script for setting iptables:

```
# Flush all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Start by blocking all traffic, this will allow secured, fine grained filtering
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Keep established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# HTTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# SSH
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# NTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT

# YUM
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

After executing the script (after `vagrant ssh`) i'm being instantly disconnected and i can't connect to the server again.

I'm wondering if that is somehow connected to vagrant port forwarding? When i do `vagrant up` console is telling that 
`default: 22 > 2222 (adapter 1)`

I added the port to `# SSH` section but still the same issue;/
Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: HI @Astaz3l , did your script eventually work when automated?

Comment: @another, yes it worked out fine, but I had to change the way it works. I'm not using iptables command directly as pointed out by @m1keil. Instead I prepare file with rules and use `iptables-restore` command. Here is nice tutorial about it: https://blacksaildivision.com/secure-iptables-rules-centos

Comment: Thanks :), I also solved my issue too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first line is `iptables -P INPUT DROP` so you are killing **ALL** the incoming connections effective **immediately**. This means that if you run your provision via SSH, you kill the provisioning ssh connection.

The solution would be to insert the rules in good order that will prevent you from locking yourself out of the machine.

Another possible solution would be to pre-save settings to file with `iptables-save` and restore on the remote machine with `iptables-restore`